# R can't be resolved into a variable in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know there are many questions about this problem but non have answered my problem.

Everytime i make a new android application project with an empty activity and layout.
it shows an error in R.layout.activity_main

heres the code:

```
package com.something.some;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

note: All this code was generated automatically by eclipse for me.

this is activity_main.xml(also automatically generated by eclipse in layout folder):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried to clean and build the project. Even creating a new project, nothing worked!
and i didn't import the "android.R"

Comment: You miss an import: `import com.something.some.R;`

Comment: i tried to import it but it didn't work

Comment: @user3560264 : Does R.java exist in the gen/ directory in your project/

Comment: I guess you already tried `Project/Clean`, `Restart Eclipse`, `check all individual xml files for the smallest error`, `check out the resource files for invalid file names`...

Comment: @DerGolem : You should never need to explicitly import your own `R` class.

Comment: @Squonk: **normally**, not. Just in case of emergency... ;)

Comment: @DerGolem: the package of that class is `com.something.some`. `import com.something.some.R;` is entirely useless. Your first comment is misleading.

Comment: @njzk2: I have some project which won't work without an import like `import com.dergolem.oneprojectofmine.R;` This is only needed in Activities and Fragments, but not in Classes... **:O**

Comment: yes i have the r.java

Comment: @DerGolem : If you have multiple packages then it *IS* necessary to import the root R.Java class in classes which need to use resources *BUT* if all code files belong to the same package then there is no need to do an explicit import. The imprt is handled implicitly by the build tools so unless you've customised build config files, it will work on a "flat" package structure.

Comment: i have only 1 package

Comment: @Squonk I organized my package in `folders` (activities, classes, fragments). Is this you mean? I can see these imports only in Activities and Fragments, but not in Classes, surprisingly enough. -> Eclipse has/had the curious habit of replacing **that** import with a funny `import android.R;`, which will **not** work.

Comment: If there is a problem with your resources that is stopping R being generated, it should show up in Window > Show View > Problems. Also, restarting Eclipse and restarting your computer can help.

Comment: already restarted computer twice. btw i have made many applications with eclispe before

Comment: R not being resolved is a very common error but it's worrying that it is happening when Eclipse generates a new application. Have you done anything to change default project structure or started using a build tool like gradle or maven? Is nothing showing in the problems tab?

Comment: tried restoring defaults and installing eclipse again!!!

Comment: Sorry to ask again but is nothing showing in the problems tab of Eclipse?

Comment: r.layout..... is being shown

Comment: Does it not give more than R.layout..... Also, `tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"` looks strange. Can you delete this line?

Comment: tried right now still it did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem once and I solved this by adjusting the last xml files before getting the error.
Try to check your xml files such that there is no warning or errors in them.

Comment: no errors or warnings even tried deleting the "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

Try importing packagename.R
You ca find the package name in the manifest file 
package="com.example.main" //example package name

In your code do:

import com.example.main.R;

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Android app in Eclipse myself I saw that apps look like they need to import the appcompat library now.

Right click the project, go to Properties, select Android and in the bottom right add the appcompat library.

You have to have imported the appcompat library as a project from your_sdk_directory/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/ (See https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html )

UPDATE: I also needed to delete the app-support-v4.jar from the libs directory of the new project.

Comment: i've always had it in my package explorer

Answer (score 0):

In the projects do you have image files?In my case was due to invalid names in images.

Comment: Not only images. **ALL** resource files are subject to file name restrictions.